# Display name from id gives me "Trying to get property 'proj_title' of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a form in which I submit an id from a "project";

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Project">Project</label>
        <select name="proj_id" class="form-control">
            @if (count($project) == 0)          
            <option>There are no projects.</option>
            @else
                @foreach($project as $project)
                    <option value="{{$project->proj_id}}">{{$project->proj_title}}</option>
                @endforeach
            @endif

        </select>
    </div>
```

This part works correctly, it inserts the proj_id into the database, but when I go back to my index I want to display the project's name from that id.
This is my index;

```
<tbody class="">
        @foreach ($task as $task)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$task->task_id}}</td>
------->    <td>{{$projects->find($task->proj_id)->proj_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->task_title}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->task_desc}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->status}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->priority}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->created_by}}</td>
            <td>{{$task->created_at}}</td>
            @if (Auth::user()->role=='admin')
            <td>
```

As it is, it gives me the error in the title.

If I change that line with `$task->proj_id` it displays that with no problem.

Also this is my index function in TaskController:

```
    public function index()
    {
        return view('tasks.index', [
            'task' => Task::all(),
            'projects' => Project::all(),
        ]);
    }
```

And these are my relations:
Project model;

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'proj_id';
    protected $fillable = ['proj_title','proj_desc','client_id','created_by'];



    public function client (){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
    public function tasks (){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
    }

}
```

Task model;

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'task_id';

    protected $fillable = ['task_title','task_desc','status','priority','person_id','proj_title','proj_id','created_by'];

    public function project(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project','proj_id');
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have `$projects` defined somewhere on your index page? Did you mean `Project::find($task->proj_id)->proj_title` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it

`<td>{{$task->project->proj_title}}</td>` and it should work fine as Task and Project has a `belongsTo` relationship, you should be able to get Project model related to `$task` using `$task->project`.

Comment: That worked for me after I did a fresh migrate, thanks. Btw, I have the same scenario with "created_by" which is an user id, I need to display the name of the user with that id. Relation is the same, but with this^^^^ code it gives me Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: @Jesus check what you are getting for `$task->project` in that case.

Comment: I get "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" for ```$task->user->name```. If I leave ```$task->name``` the field just stays blank but it doesnt give an error

Comment: @Jesus Is there any relation on Task model for User model?

Comment: I just figured it out. It was that I had to indicate my foreign key. Thank you so much, your reply was really helpful!

Comment: @Jesus I am glad it helped you.